# Start/Stop Instance VM automalically with scheduler GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying through Scheduler, run a job to shut down and turn on the instance.
Already created the service account, put some permissions, tried several, but every time I run the job gives authentication error.
What am I doing wrong?

```
{
 httpRequest: {…}
 insertId: "10wqtpjg1aco1ta"
 jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
  jobName: "projects / manifest-welder-xxxxx / locations / us-central1 / jobs / Stop16Solution"
  status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  targetType: "HTTP"
  url: "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/manifest-welder-xxxxx/zones/us-central1-a/instances/server16solution/stop"
 }
 logName: "projects / manifest-welder-254710 / logs / cloudscheduler.googleapis.com% 2Fexecutions"
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-10-17T23: 23: 46.369687313Z"
 resource: {…}
 severity: "ERROR"
 timestamp: "2019-10-17T23: 23: 46.369687313Z"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which roles are you assigning to the service account for Cloud Scheduler? If the Compute Engine instance is assigned a service account, the Cloud Scheduler also needs the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`. Give the Cloud Scheduler the role `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1` to stop and start VMs.

Comment: Good Morning!!!
I put the following rules and it didn't work
Cloud Scheduler Job Executor
Cloud Scheduler Service Agent
Compute Instance Administrator (v1)
Service Account User

Comment: My guess is that you are assigning these roles to the wrong service account.

Comment: I removed your screenshot because your project-id was visible in the service account. does your error contain authenticationInfo:    principalEmail: "xxxx"? it will tell you the account that is missing permissions

Comment: @ErnestoU - Just so that you know this, we can still see the edit changes. Editing a question does not remove information. Also, Project IDs are not secrets. Without authorization, Project IDs are useless. In the future if you see secrets accidentally disclosed flag the question for a moderator to delete/edit the question.